# Unable to refresh custom view in Layout

Tags: android, layout, view, android-linearlayout

In my `onCreateView` i have the following codes to populate custom view into my `LinearLayout` whereby `StageViewer` extends `View`.

```
layout = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lo1);     

for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i ++)
{

  StageViewer viewer = new StageViewer(i,callingActivity,this, 0, Global.STAGE_VIEW);
  layout.addView(viewer);
  stageList.add(viewer);        
}
```

In my application the user have a option to set all view to default mode

```
public void resetToDefault()
{

  for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i ++)
  {

    StageViewer viewer = new StageViewer(i,callingActivity,this, 0, Global.STAGE_VIEW);
    layout.addView(viewer);
    stageList.add(viewer);      

  }

}
```

However upon reset the new view are NOT viewable (an empty layout is shown).

I tried

```
viewer.invalidate();
layout.refreshDrawableState();
```

Did I miss out something ?

Comment: Does your `StageViewer`shows up in a static layout at all?

Comment: yes. it shows up on a static layout . it also shows up when it is populated in the inital onCreateView call

Answer (score 0):

```
public void resetToDefault()
{
  layout.removeAllViews();
   stageList.clear();
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i ++)
  {

    StageViewer viewer = new StageViewer(i,callingActivity,this, 0, Global.STAGE_VIEW);
    layout.addView(viewer);
    stageList.add(viewer);      
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi , i tried your solution but is still the same. Any other possibility ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe layout params are missing?

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
viewer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
layout.addView(viewer);
```

Comment: Check out resulting layout in Dump View Hierarchy. You will see borders or your views. Thus might help with problem localization.

Comment: Hi beworker, After much troubleshooting i found that the onMeasure ofor the custom view yield a width of 160 on inital creation (via oncreateview). however , it shows a width of 0 for resettodefault.